# Parse.com: Pushing messages within a short time frame

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, parse-platform

My requirement is to send the same message to 10.000 - 15.000 different clients (iOS and Android devices).

All those messages need to be delivered in a really short time ( 0 - 20 seconds max)

Is Parse.com useful for this type of scenario, where the messages need to arrive as soon as possible in a short time frame.

Any experience using Parse will be welcome.

I made the same [question](https://parse.com/questions/pushing-messages-within-a-short-time-frame) in Parse.com forums 5 days ago, but no answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just set the PUSH Notification ... Here's how to create the push notificatioin as a send to all of your users both iOS and Android at the same time creating a PFnstallation dividiere for your users from iOS to Android .. is very simple ...

https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide # top / iOS

Comment: Rory, I know how to do it. But I would like to know if Parse.com Push Messages will be delivered in no more than 20 seconds.

Comment: I understand, scuami are Italian and the translator often making jokes. So, normally the push always come within 20 seconds. We must consider aspects such as:

Comment: The user who receives the push has internet connection at that time? Maybe at that time no and so here we already have the first delay.
(This you can 'overcome by inserting the code Push the project file that the push notification has a duration of 20 days so if the user has problems or does not have the phone line for any reason, may still receive the push by a certain date).
You should consider all the circumstances that cause delays due to not push because as I said until now, I never had a problem similar to your question. ;)